# Failed to query external table via PXF

Tags: greenplum

I made a GPDB(greenplum-db-5.18.0) cluster with one master and 3 segment hosts. And following this [link](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5180/pxf/client_instcfg.html), I configured kerberos and hdfs core xmls, and PXF service startup successfully. While I run a query pointing to remote hdfs file, it keeps giving error log like :

```
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSClient.getQuotaUsage(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/QuotaUsage; @160: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/ContentSummary' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/QuotaUsage' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @160
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSClient', 'java/lang/String', 'org/apache/hadoop/ipc/RemoteException', 'java/io/IOException' }
```

The PXF service is started with openjdk 1.8.0_131. And our hdfs cluster is based on hadoop mdh 2.6.0.4, so I put hadoop-*2.6.0-mdh2.6.0.4.jar into $PXF_CONF/lib, while GPDB 5.18 itself is based on hadoop 2.8.5. Is it a conflict for this error?

I found one issue alike in error but without definite solution:[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515890/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-verifyerror-bad-type-on-operand-stack)

BTW, is there any other thing I missed for accessing hdfs file with PXF such as setting HADOOP VERSION via gpconfig, which is not mentioned in the guide doc.

Answer (score 1):

PXF is compatible with Cloudera, Hortonworks Data Platform, MapR, and generic Apache Hadoop distributions. Microsoft's (Microsoft Distribution of Hadoop (MDH)) is not within the release notes.

https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5180/pxf/client_instcfg.html

Comment: That said, are you trying to access Azure Blob Storage?
If so, you don't need the Hadoop configuration -- PXF has a special protocol for that... `wabs:`

Comment: The error looks like hadoop lib dependency conflict. Try removing the libs you added to PXF_CONF/lib.

Comment: @SungYu-wei, I tried it before posting, it shows another exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.FederatedDFSFileSystem not found

Comment: @BrendanStephens  I don't need to access Azure Blob Storage, just our hdfs cluster.

Comment: @BrendanStephens er, sorry for mdh misunderstanding. mdh is not short for Microsoft, but for customized version based on apache hadoop in our company. It's based on apache hadoop 2.6. So it should be compatible with GPDB 5.18.0

Comment: It is not supported then. You probably need to customize pxf plugin for your MDH.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning out your $PXF_CONF/lib folder. In general, the libraries that we ship are sufficient to connect to most hadoop distributions. I would suggest you try the following:

```
$ rm -rf $PXF_CONF/lib/*
$ $PXF_HOME/bin/pxf restart
```

If you are on a multinode cluster, you will need to remove the jar files from $PXF_CONF/lib/ manually on each segment host, and then restart the PXF cluster.

Comment: I did it before this posting, it shows ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.FederatedDFSFileSystem not found

Comment: Can you try only copying the following files to $PXF_CONF/lib
- ${HADOOP_COMMON}/lib/hadoop-auth-*.jar 
- ${HADOOP_COMMON}/hadoop-common-*.jar